# Crear formulario de forma dinámica usando Google App Script y Google App Maker

Tags: formularios, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

He estado buscando información acerca de cómo crear formularios dinámicos usando Google App Script y Google App Maker. Encontré que antes se hacía con UiApp pero al parecer lo que dice esta pagina ya quedó obsoleto y según la documentación probablemente se retire en un futuro de Apps Script:

http://www.googleappsscript.org/miscellaneous/creating-form-elements-dynamically-using-google-apps-script-gas

También en otras respuestas comentan que se puede hacer un modelo de datos y asociándolo a una lista o tabla pero no encontré información concreta acerca de como hacer esto.

Hay ejemplos en el sitio oficial de Google Developers pero me es imposible acceder a ellos ya que no tengo una cuenta administrativa con Cloud SQL activado.

Lo que quiero hacer es generar radio botones y mostrarlos en la pantalla, me podría ayudar incluso un ejemplo en el que esto se haga con un arreglo o lista pero no eh encontrado algo así.

¿Alguien sabe como generar este tipo de formularios de forma dinámica?

===================================================================
Actualización.

No estoy muy seguro del formato para añadir detalles o actualizaciones a la consulta que les hago aquí ya que esta es mi primera publicación pero vengo a reportar como va el caso que les comento.

Ya pude hacer que las preguntas aparecieran de forma dinamica en el formulario usando una tabla y un "Calculated Model" el cual lleno con la informacion que tengo en la base de datos, adjunto a continuacion la captura de pantalla:

[image: La tabla en el editor se ve asi, el datasource se llama Questions]

[image: Las preguntas y respuestas en forma de radio botón son consultadas desde la base de datos por la aplicación y mostradas de forma dinámica dentro de la Tabla]

Publicare como fue que lo hice con mas detalle pero antes necesito saber ¿Como puedo recolectar las respuestas de  los elementos que se encuentran dentro de esta tabla usando Google App Script?

No encuentro como hacer esto usando la instruccion:

var table = widget.root.descendants.tblPreguntas.descendants;

De nuevo comento que lo que estoy haciendo es una aplicacion que utiliza Google App Script y Google App Maker.

Lo que quiero es que al darle clic a un botón me recolecte las respuestas seleccionadas en los radio botones de cada fila por que estas las guardare en la base de datos.

Las funciones y demás que hacen el guardado de la información en la base de datos ya las tengo listas , lo único que necesito saber es ¿Como leer estas respuestas de la tabla que les muestro en la imagen?

Perdón si no redacto con detalle como le hice para generar las preguntas de forma dinámica por si a alguien le llega a servir en un futuro pero es por la limitante de tiempo que tengo para hacer esto, sin embargo en cuanto acabe lo haré.

Agradezco de nuevo su atención.

Comment: necesitamos más información para saber que es lo que buscas exactamente, podrías mostrar alguna pantalla o parte de tu código, eso ayudaría mucho, creo que ya revisaste el app maker, solo es cosa de jalar widgets y darles funcionalidad, no comprendo bien si lo que deseas es crear widgets dependiendo de la cantidad de elementos de tu base de datos, para ello existe el grid, te crea los elemento que tiene tu base de datos o los posibles valores que tu le hayas añadido manualmente dentro del programa.

Comment: Ya pude generar el formulario y  es correcto, las preguntas las tengo guardadas en una base de datos, ahora solo necesito saber como guardar lo que selecciono el usuario al dar clic en un boton.  ¿Hay alguna funcion en Google App Script que me permita leerlas?

Comment: El modelo de datos lo tiene asignado un widget tabla que agregue a la aplicacion , lo que no se es como recolectar los valores de los  radio botones que tiene dentro. Por lo que estuve investigando no hay algo como una fila y una columna en App Maker pero lo que no se es como leer los radio  botones que me genera, ya puse otra captura de pantalla mostrando como luce el componente en el editor

Comment: Intente agrega la descripcion que me da el editor de este foro pero como que la misma no se ve por eso la comento aqui. 

En la primera imagen el datasource que use se llama Questions ahi es donde se guarda el texto y las posibles respuestas temporalmente para cargarse a la tabla. 

La segunda imagen es de la tabla ya con el cuestionario cargado desde base de datos.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque App Maker dejó de estar disponible en enero de acuerdo a https://support.google.com/a/answer/9682494?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que has creado una aplicación usando Google App Maker en la que cuentas con un modelo calculado y página en la que has colocado botones de radio (radio buttons) y que deseas que al hacer clic en un botón los valores de los botones de radio se envíen a una base de datos externa.

La pregunta concreta es cómo obtener los valores de los botones de radio.

Lo primero que debes hacer es asociar las propiedad "value" a una propiedad personalizada (custom property) de la página ya que no cuentas con datos de SQL en el que puedas escribir.

Luego deberás crear unos scripts ya sea locales (en la página o widgets) o globales (archivos de código del lado del cliente). Una forma de obtener lo valores, aprovechando que se han vinculado a las propiedades personalizadas de la página sería

```
var radio1 = app.currentPage.properties.botonRadio1;
```

donde `botonRadio1` es el nombre de la propiedad personalizada.